# Repeating reactive output in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display the same reactive text output at multiple locations in an R Shiny app.  Here is a simple example (in a single R markdown document):

````
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
```

```{r}
output$text1 <- renderText({ 
  paste("Selected letter:", input$var)
})

fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    selectInput("var", label="Choose a letter", choices=letters[1:4], selected="b")
    ),
  fluidRow(
    textOutput("text1")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    textOutput("text1")
  )
)
```
````

This code works fine if I delete the middle `fluidRow(textOutput("text1")),` with the app showing the initial text ***Selected letter:*** and the reactive input ***b*** once.  But, if I leave that piece of code in, it doesn't display the same text twice, as I expected it would.  Instead, the app shows the initial text ***Selected letter:*** only once and the reactive input ***b*** not at all.

---

For completeness, I am adding example code (for the second chunk) that provides a work around.

```
n <- 2
for(i in seq(n)) {
  output[[paste0("text",i )]] <- renderText(paste("Selected letter:", input$var))
}

fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    selectInput("var", label = "Choose a letter",
      choices = letters[1:4], selected = "b")
    ),
  fluidRow(
    textOutput("text1")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    textOutput("text2")
  )
)
```

Comment: You cannot have two outputs with the same id.

Comment: Thanks for that information.  If you provide that as an answer, I will accept it.  Can you point to a place where that is stated explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shiny Inputs/Outputs must have unique IDs. Quote from http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

> Input and output IDs in Shiny apps share a global namespace, meaning,
>   each ID must be unique across the entire app. If you’re using
>   functions to generate UI, and those functions generate inputs and
>   outputs, then you need to ensure that none of the IDs collide.

Shiny Modules and Namespaces provide a way to organize your code and avoid name collisions.